# Div's with different heights, align them side by side at the top

Tags: css

I want to align divs side by side, but the heights are not equal, which causes that there is a blank space between div's the first line with lower height and the div's in the second row.

I want this:

[image]

and not this:

[image]

Comment: Use `position:absolute;` and `float:left;`

Comment: Do you have any code..?

Comment: I'll create a fiddle.

Comment: you could make wraps for 1&4, 2&5 and 3&6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Floating Divs with different height are aligned with space between them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628311/css-floating-divs-with-different-height-are-aligned-with-space-between-them)

Answer (score 1):

I would use 3 divs (lets call them A B and C) as columns

These would have style="float:left;width:32%;" * note width CAN be less than 32% and can be set in px

A would contain 1 and 4 while B would contain 2 and 5. Finally C would contain 3 and 6.

There is absolutely no need for plugins and it can (and is currently, by me) being done with css alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with CSS alone, unless you are willing to position each div absolutely, which isn't much fun.

Other options include

- grouping each column in a separate div
- using JavaScript, such as a script like Masonry

Comment: using a  "wrapper" divs and CSS will allow this to be done without absolute positioning or involving Javascript in any way

Comment: Yes, that's why it's the best way to go for a simple static layout. It's not so useful in a CMS where the elements are generated dynamically, unfortunately, or in a responsive site where you want elements to reflow.

Answer (score -2):

use `margin-top: -20px;` for div 4 and div 6...

-20 is example of course