# Floating different height divs

Tags: css

I have a series of divs, all with the same width, but some with different heights.

I want it to look like this, with no gaps between the divs, flowing nicely underneath each other

[image]

But no matter what I try (I've just been floating them left) it looks like this:

```
    .item
{
```

float: left;
}

[Fiddle to show what I don't want...](https://jsfiddle.net/mo5kb6cm/)

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this question has the general answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106578/position-floated-elements-directly-under-each-other

Comment: Deffinitively, it is a duplicate of [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628311/css-floating-divs-with-different-height-are-aligned-with-space-between-them)